# C struct of structs initialization

Tags: c, struct, reference, initialization, typedef

I'm a little confused about the best way to initialize complex structs
(struct of struct)

I basically have a setup like this

```
typedef struct {
    float x;
    float y;
} Vectorf;

typedef struct {
    Vectorf position;
    Vectorf direction;
    Vectorf velocity;
} Player;
```

What would be the best way to initialize a Player object?

Variant A

```
Vectorf position = {1.0f, 1.0f};
Vectorf direction = {1.0f, 0.0f};
Vectorf velocity = {0.0f, 0.0f};

Player player = {position, direction, velocity};
```

Variant B

```
Player *player = malloc(sizeof(Player));

player->position.x = 1.0f;
player->position.y = 1.0f;
player->direction.x = 1.0f;
player->direction.y = 0.0f;
player->velocity.x = 0.0f;
player->velocity.y = 0.0f;

--- Stuff ---

free(player);
```

Or even create a function like

```
Player *createPlayer(float px, float py...)
Player createPlayer(float px, float py...)
```

But inside these I would need Variant A or B again I guess.

Is it just a matter of taste or are there benefits for either?

I also have something like this

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
    Texture *texture;
    bool walkable;
} Tile;

typedef struct {
    int width;
    int height;
    Tile *tiles;
} Map;
```

Here a create function seems more reasonable, because I can pass actual map data.

Comment: If you use `malloc` then `Player *createPlayer(float px, float py...)` is good. If you use a local `struct` then `Player createPlayer(float px, float py...)` is good. It might depend on what you want to do with each `Player`. If you want several references to the same player (for example in  a team, in a performance profile, etc)  I would go the pointer route, rather than replicate the `struct` for each.

Comment: So it's a matter of complexity and access times? If for example the Player object contains more references to other complex data it`s better to pass it with a pointer to avoid copying.

Comment: If any data is dynamic it should be in one place only: not needing to be updated in several places - that creates a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that answer should be *depends on your needs*, both ways of creating
objects are OK.

Sometimes you don't need to worry about allocation memory with `malloc` if you
are going to use an object only a couple of times and you don't need that the
objects "survives" when the function exits. So your variant A would be OK.

Sometimes you want to create a lot of objects and store them in other data structures (lists, trees, etc),
and you need the objects to "live" throughout the whole program. In this case your
variant B would be the better. AnT's answer shows you how you could save lines
of code for initialization.

The other time when I consider using `malloc` is
when I know that the struct is very large and would consume lots of bytes for
each object, so having a lot of them could potentially eat up all your stack. In
that case I'd rather have these large objects in the heap, and also handling
with pointers is much cheaper than having to creates copies when calling
function that do not take pointers.

I also use `malloc` when I see the structs as classes and I want a clean API for
creating, using and destryoing them. I always use prefix for the functions and I
always have a create, init and free function for every object type, something
like this:

```
typedef struct abc {
    // lot's of members
} Abc;

Abc *abc_create(void);
int abc_init(Abc *abc); // always with default values
void abc_free(Abc *abc);

int abc_do_A(Abc *abc, int x);
int abc_do_B(Abc *abc, int y);
....
```

and the three first functions usually look like this:

```
Abc *abc_create(void)
{
    Abc *abc = calloc(1, sizeof *abc);
    if(abc == NULL)
        return NULL;

    if(abc_init(abc) == 1)
        return abc;

    free(abc);
    return NULL;
}

int abc_init(Abc *abc)
{
    if(abc == NULL)
        return 0;

    // initializations
    ...

    return 1;
}

void abc_free(Abc *abc)
{
    if(abc == NULL)
        return;

    // do free of other malloced
    // members if present
    free(abc);
}
```

I think this gives you a very clear and easy API to use. I maintain a C library
at work where I have at least 50+ of these structs, all with the same scheme,
using them it's easy because they all behave like this:

```
Abc *abc = abc_create(1, 2, 3);
if(abc == NULL)
{
    error handling
}

abc_do_A(abc, 12);
abc_do_A(abc, 11);
...
abc_free(abc); // when not needed anymore
```

Comment: I realize now, that my question wasn't properly asked. This is what it's actually about. Objects like Player or Map sit in memory for the whole program cycle and get shared a lot. So it makes sense to malloc them and pass with pointers. The whole malloc / free thing made me feel uncomfortable because it seemed quite daunting. And still, writing a lot of free functions which are basically the same sounds weird.

Answer (score 2):

```
Player player = {.position = {1.0f, 1.0f}, 
             .direction = {1.0f, 0.0f},
             .velocity = {0.0f, 0.0f}};
```

Note this won't work in C++. Only in C.

Comment: Did not know about that. It's short and maintains readability. I like it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For Variant A

```
Player player = { { 1., 1. }, { 1., 0. }, { 0., 0. } };
```

You can also use a tagged variant for better clarity and readability, as in @dev_null's answer.

For Variant B *compound literals* will help you

```
Player *player = malloc(sizeof *player);

*player = (Player) { { 1., 1. }, { 1., 0. }, { 0., 0. } };
```

If you have a `memdup`-like functionality at your disposal, you can implement Variant B as an one-liner

```
/* Assuming `void *memdup(const void *src, size_t size);` */

Player *player = memdup(
  &(Player) { { 1., 1. }, { 1., 0. }, { 0., 0. } },
  sizeof *player);
```

Again, feel free to use a tagged version, if you like it better.

Compound literals allow you to mix-and-match your original approach and `{}`-based approach, if you for some reason decide that it is beneficial

```
Player *player = malloc(sizeof *player);

player->position = (Vectorf) { 1., 1. };
player->direction = (Vectorf) { 1., 0. }; 
player->velocity = (Vectorf) { 0., 0. };
```

Comment: Thank you for these Variants. Although they get hard to read I guess.